# Swift textViewDidBeginEditing and textViewDidEndEditing Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textview, uitextview

I'm trying to get my `UITextView` `feedbackInput` to delete the placeholder text when it's clicked inside of and then let the user type in the `UITextView` in a black font color. Also if the user clicks inside of the `UITextView`, but doesn't type anything and then clicks outside of it, the placeholder text should be redisplayed. Currently, my code loads the placeholder text correctly, but when the user clicks inside of the `UITextView` the placeholder text isn't immediately removed and the user can only type in the `UITextView` in the light gray placeholder text font color, not in black.

`AddMeal` View Code:

```
import SwiftUI

class AddMeal: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @State var stars = -1
    var feedbackInput = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 440, width: 372, height: 100))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        
        // Add Meal Title Label
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
        label.center = self.view.center
        label.center.x = self.view.center.x
        label.center.y = 75
        label.font = label.font.withSize(30);
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        label.text = "Add Meal"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        
        // Meal Title Label
        let food = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 22, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50))
        food.font = label.font.withSize(20);
        food.textColor = .white
        food.text = "Meal Title"
        self.view.addSubview(food)
        
        // Food Title Input Text Field
        let sampleTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 150, width: 372, height: 40))
        sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter the Name of the Food or Drink..."
        sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
        sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
        sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
        self.view.addSubview(sampleTextField)
        
        // Meal Calories Label
        let mealCalories = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 22, y: 200, width: 200, height: 50))
        mealCalories.font = label.font.withSize(20);
        mealCalories.textColor = .white
        mealCalories.text = "Meal Calories"
        self.view.addSubview(mealCalories)
        
        // Calories Input Text Field
        let sampleTextField2 =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 250, width: 372, height: 40))
        sampleTextField2.placeholder = "Enter the # of Calories..."
        sampleTextField2.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        sampleTextField2.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
        sampleTextField2.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        sampleTextField2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        sampleTextField2.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        sampleTextField2.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
        sampleTextField2.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
        self.view.addSubview(sampleTextField2)
        
        // Meal Rating Label
        let mealRating = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 22, y: 300, width: 200, height: 50))
        mealRating.font = label.font.withSize(20);
        mealRating.textColor = .white
        mealRating.text = "Meal Rating"
        self.view.addSubview(mealRating)
        
        // Rating Stars
        let stars = UIHostingController(rootView: StarsView())
        self.view.addSubview(stars.view)
        self.addChild(stars)
        stars.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        stars.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stars.view.sizeToFit()
        stars.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mealRating.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        stars.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // Meal Feedback Label
        let mealFeedback = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 22, y: 390, width: 200, height: 50))
        mealFeedback.font = label.font.withSize(20);
        mealFeedback.textColor = .white
        mealFeedback.text = "Meal Feedback"
        self.view.addSubview(mealFeedback)
        
        // Feedback Input Field
        feedbackInput.delegate = self
        feedbackInput.text = "Enter Your Feedback on the Meal..."
        feedbackInput.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        feedbackInput.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        feedbackInput.textColor = .lightGray
        self.view.addSubview(feedbackInput)
    }
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == .lightGray {
        textView.text = ""
        textView.textColor = .black
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.text = "Enter Your Feedback on the Meal..."
        textView.textColor = .lightGray
    }
}

struct StarsView: View {
    @State var stars = -1
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<5){ i in
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .resizable().frame(width: 30, height:30)
                    .foregroundColor(self.stars >= i ? .yellow : .gray)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.stars = i
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Image of Current Output:

[image: Output]

How can I fix the issue of `textViewDidBeginEditing` and `textViewDidEndEditing` not being called correctly for my `UITextView` `feedbackInput` to work properly as I described above?

Comment: You are not setting the text view delegate.

Comment: @ElTomato I did set the UITextView delegate in this line: feedbackInput.delegate = self. Is there another way that I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `placeholder`, not `text`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
    ...

    mealFeedback.placeholder = "Meal Feedback"
    feedbackInput.placeholder = "Enter Your Feedback on the Meal..."
}
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == .lightGray {
        textView.placeholder = ""
        textView.textColor = .black
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.placeholder = "Enter Your Feedback on the Meal..."
        textView.textColor = .lightGray
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try doing this I get an error saying that the UITextView has no member "placeholder". Any other ideas?

Comment: @ERACED ah I forgot placeholder was only for UITextField

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate callbacks are **outside** of your view controller context, but must be **inside**

```
class AddMeal: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    // @State var stars = -1 // << !! BTW, don't use state here - it will not work

// ... other code

  func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == .lightGray {
        textView.text = ""
        textView.textColor = .black
    }
  }

  func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.text = "Enter Your Feedback on the Meal..."
        textView.textColor = .lightGray
    }
  }
}
```